# Unzip using VSTS build

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am unable to unzip the file using VSTS git.

I have tried using unzip, extract file, unzip file but none shows the unzipped file after the build is successfully run

Comment: Please elaborate a little more, adding some image and more information on your question please.

Comment: Can you share detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: What i want to do is i have a zip file in the VSTS git and i want that zip file to be unziped by using unzip tool. I tried with unzip tool by mentioning zip files to unzip as $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cicdadf.zip and unzip to path as $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s\test1 but i dont see a folder created as test1 nor i see the files being extracted.

Comment: LOGS : https://drive.google.com/file/d/13nngHdN_bOV-aehn_nJTpSaZjBcr_XSx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RodrigoWerlang

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT

Comment: Do you use Hosted agent? How do you check the files? What're tasks of your build definition?

Comment: yes there is an hosted agent. Build link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GuLHK3MnK8z8HmAiVVgetFRlNx18sdJ5/view?usp=sharing

Rep where zip file is stored and which i want to unzip : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NgJpLMoynDkejNtlupK0MWJOcZt7maRC/view?usp=sharing

@starianchen-MSFT

Comment: Since you are using Hosted agent? How do you check whether the zip file has been unzipped or not?

Comment: The file is unzipped to the agent folder.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT i want the file to be unzipped in the same place where you see the zipped file. 

How do i check my agent folder?

Comment: Do you mean you want the unzipped files are uploaded to git repository?

Comment: What's the detail requirement?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT : Detailed requirement : I want the files inside the zipped folder to be unzipped and shown in the same place where the zipped file is located as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168535/discussion-between-ashish-and-starian-chen-msft).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to these steps below to push unzipped files to git repository:

1. Go to Admin page of that team project (`https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project name}/_admin/_versioncontrol?repoGroup=true&_a=security`)
2. Select corresponding repository
3. Select `Project Collection Build Service (xxx)` user and change **Contribute** permission to Allow
4. Edit build definition, select the Phase and check **Allow scripts to access OAuth token** option
5. Upzip zip files to a directory task: Zip files to unzip: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cicdadf.zip`; Upzip to path:`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`
6. Command line task: Tool: `git`; Arguments: `config --global user.email you@example.com`. Working folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`
7. Command line task: Tool: `git`; Aeguments: `config --global user.name "Your Name"`; Working folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`
8. Command line task: Tool: `git`; Arguments: `add cicdadf/**`; Working folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`
9. Command line task: Tool: `git`; Aeguments: `commit -m "add unzipped files"`; Working folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`
10. Command line task: Tool: `git`; Aeguments: `push https://test:$(System.AccessToken)@{account}.visualstudio.com/{team project}/_git/{respository} HEAD:master`; Working folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added path variables correctly. The default relative path is the folder where all sources for the build definition are synced. You can go thought other directories/files on the build agent by using full paths or variables in the path. All input boxes for paths do accept variables. For example the source directory is: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s. Or use your own variables for the build/release pipeline in the paths.

Reference:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=petergroenewegen.PeterGroenewegen-Xpirit-Vsts-Build-Zip

Comment: Hi Sheethal thanks for the prompt response.
What i want to do is i have a zip file in the VSTS git and i want that zip file to be unziped by using unzip tool. I tried with unzip tool by mentioning zip files to unzip as $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\cicdadf.zip and unzip to path as $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\s\test1 but i dont see a folder created as test1 nor i see the files being extracted.